# First appearance of stopping an elevator to have a private discussion (Elevator Conference)

Tags: first-appearance

I watch NCIS for years, and was always sure the "elevator trick" (aka Elevator Conference) Gibbs is doing sometimes (stopping the elevator in the middle of its ride without actually ringing any bells or  summoning a rescue) was invented by that TV show, e.g. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcbs6L2P1zk#t=0m12s).

However, few days ago I noticed it was already done nearly 20 years ago, in Friends! (S06E08)

[image]
<sub>([image source](http://fullepisodes.biz/friends-s06e08-season-6-episode-8-the-one-with-ross-teeth-s6e8-with-english-subtitles_6c70b881e.html))</sub>

So my question is: what is the first appearance of such a thing in a TV show or a movie?

Comment: TV Tropes calls this [Elevator Conference](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ElevatorConference). There are more examples, but nothing about a first.

Comment: @Kruga thanks, really wondered what is the official term. :)

Comment: It could be related to *The Secret Of My Success* in which Michael J. Fox's character stops the elevator to change from his mailroom clothes to his executive suit and back. In the end, there's a sort of "elevator conference" where Fox and the female lead stop the elevator to have a private romantic moment. Looks like if any elevator conference will do, then *Star Trek: TOS* is the one to beat. They didn't emergency stop the turbolifts though.

Comment: @Todd thanks, Star Trek is indeed less relevant, probably. When was "The Secret Of My Success" published?

Comment: 1987 http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093936/?ref_=nv_sr_2